# typeof for a string returning object

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, "this" is a string but the condition check fails. Help me understand the logic behind it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does console.log prints?

Comment: console.log prints object

Comment: Yes as @Boldewyn answered. `this` is typeof object. it's not primitive string. to check if the instace is object or not you can do `this instanceOf Object` it will return true or false.

Comment: "*As shown in the screenshot, "this" is a string*"  the screenshot shows it's a String - capital "S". So, it's an object, not a primitive string (lowercase "s").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has a pecurliar feature. You can have explicit object wrappers around primitive types. Dr. Rauschmayer explains it rather well in this article: https://2ality.com/2011/03/javascript-values-not-everything-is.html

Example:

```
> typeof "abc"
'string'
> typeof new String("abc")
'object'
```

`this` in your context will be such a wrapper object. It behaves *almost* like its primitive counterpart, but `typeof` is such a condition, where they differ.

Comment: Worth adding to this that strict mode makes this behavior go away, and you get the unwrapped primitive as `this`.

Comment: I’ve tried `(function() {"use strict"; console.log(typeof new String("abc"));})()` and it still shows `object`. Have you a source for that info? This behaviour in strict mode would actually surprise me.

Comment: What I mean is that `this` will not be automatically wrapped in strict mode: `'use strict'; (function() { console.log(this, typeof this); }).call('hello');` outputs `hello, string` Whereas without the strict mode you would get `[String 'hello'] object`

Comment: Good point, yes. Thanks for the clarification!